# Deleting orphan records created by Snapshot restore

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have many snapshot restorations in my instance. Due to which I can see there are orphan records (with Company ID in negative).

It’s on many tables, not just this one. Is there a process or best practice to clean this out? Or do we go table by table to run delete scripts to records that are not valid companyid.

Please suggest.

Comment: negative company values are snapshots. If you dont want the company snapshot you can following Gabriels answer which is a quick sql method to remove them. From the UI you can use the Tenant/Company screen to delete old snapshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pp_DeleteCompany stored procedure to delete the orphan snapshots. Example: EXEC pp_DeleteCompany -1234567 (assuming the CompanyID is -1234567)

Comment: Will Deleting Snapshot from Acumatica not delete all orphan records or I have to go directly to SQL?

Comment: It will, but based on your question i assumed that the snapshot was already deleted from a acumatica and no longer visible in the snapshot list - orphaned.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel and Brendan