# How to clean the data from tables which are created from old snapshots

Tags: acumatica

I will restore snapshot from sandbox instance to my local instance for every one week, when i restore the snapshot the data in the table with unwanted companyIDs are still exists, as these data is not useful, so, how can i delete the data from table with unwanted companyIDs, is it ok if i run a delete script, or is their any better way to do, please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting orphan records created by Snapshot restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494912/deleting-orphan-records-created-by-snapshot-restore)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the pp_DeleteCompany stored procedure to delete the orphan snapshots and records. Example: EXEC pp_DeleteCompany -1234567 (assuming the CompanyID is -1234567)